# LINQ Join On Int = Char DataTypes?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I wrote up the following LINQ query to join two tables based on a common (what I thought to be) integer:

```
Dim test = 
    (From forecast In dtForecast.AsEnumerable() Join dns In dtDns.AsEnumerable()
       On forecast.Field(Of Int32)("BrandId") 
       Equals dns.Field(Of Int32)("SalesCategory01Code")
    Select New With 
    { 
         .Key = forecast.Field(Of String)("BrandName") 
    }).ToList()
```

However, it throws the exception `Specified cast is not valid`

I've since discovered that the BrandId column is an `int` and the SalesCategory01Code column is setup as a `char(6)`.

Is it possible to modify this and make the join work using LINQ?

Comment: How would you like `char(6)` to be transformed into `int` when `int` has 4 bytes only?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I think that's more of a database design issue, as the `MAX(SalesCategory01Code)` from the database is `600`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL `nchar`maps to a C# `string`([http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d496c385-e0d9-4b98-81a4-1181270ea030/sql-server-vs-c-data-types?forum=sqlexpress)), so cast it accordingly and use `Int32.Parse`:

```
Dim test = 
    (From forecast In dtForecast.AsEnumerable() Join dns In dtDns.AsEnumerable()
       On forecast.Field(Of Int32)("BrandId") 
       Equals Int32.Parse(dns.Field(Of String)("SalesCategory01Code"))
    Select New With 
    { 
         .Key = forecast.Field(Of String)("BrandName") 
    }).ToList()
```

You could also modify your sql query that selects the data and cast it there:

```
 SELECT SalesCategory01Code = CAST(SalesCategory01Code as int)...
```

Comment: `char(1)` is mapped to `char` in my SQL/C# world.